# Auto open intend applications in flutter webview app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using Fly web android flutter app source code. How to open youtube app when a button in webpage is clicked . HomeScree.dart

Answer (score 0):

Force opening an app from a link would be a threat to user settings (pop-up to choose browser or app). I am pretty sure that using the link instead of app is the only way, especially when its a web view